# How do I search ALL locations (including Remote drives) for a particular filename in Windows 7 (64b)?

Tags: windows-7

Remote drives are not indexed by Windows 7.

I'd like to be able to quickly start a search of ALL locations for a filename pattern (filename: *keyword*.xls, etc.)

Is there a quick way to *start* this search?

What I've tried:

1. Select Computer
2. Type in search.  (I'd prefer a shortcut key or
   something)

Comment: I think the only option is to search for a third party File Explorer

Comment: What's wrong with searching via the method you say you've tried? Too slow?  Not searching the folders you want?  Fires pink rabbits out of your keyboard?  You may not be able to "quickly" search a non-indexed drive, since speeding up lookups is what the indexes are for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just click start, type something, press enter and then in the window click Search again in "computer". And yes it searches through network drives too ;)

If you want to index network locations I read Windows Desktop Search 4.0 does that
http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/150611-windows-desktop-search-4-0-and-network-drives
but people don't seem to recommend that much :-]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "Everything" from http://voidtools.com/ will solve your problem?

Comment: 1.10 Can "Everything" index a mapped network drive?
No, "Everything" only indexes local or removable NTFS volumes.

To search a networked computer you will need to run Everything on both computers.
One computer will need to Start an ETP server.
The other computer will need to connect to that ETP server.